# MONGO insertMany() not showing results

Tags: mongodb, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to insert records in a collection that I created (ProductCatalog). I was able to successfully insert records for book portion. However, upon executing the insertMany() function again for the laptop portion, there is no output or error message displayed. I checked the ProductCatalog (.find()) and the laptop records are not reflected as well. I already closed the cmd and restarted but to no avail.

```
> db.ProductCatalog.insertMany([{
... {
... "id":"001",
... "type":"laptop",
... "brand":"Apple",
... "name":"Macbook air",
... "price":2000,
... "size":
... {
... "long":12,
... "width":20,
... "high":5
... },
... "colour":"white",
... "capacity":
... {
... "weight":"1.4kg",
... "memory":"8GB",
... "HDD":"1TB"
... }
... }, {
... "id":"002",
... "type":"laptop",
... "brand":"HP",
... "name":"Model S",
... "price":1500,
... "size":
... {
... "long":13,
... "width":25,
... "high":10
... },
... "colour":"blue",
... "capacity":
... {
... "weight":"1.4kg",
... "memory":"10GB",
... "HDD":"2TB"
... }
... }, {
... "id":"003",
... "type":"laptop",
... "brand":"Dell",
... "name":"Model X",
... "price":2500,
... "size":
... {
... "long":15
... "width":20
... "high":15
... },
... "colour":"pink",
... "capacity":
... {
... "weight":"1.8kg",
... "memory":"5GB",
... "HDD":"1TB"
... }
... }]);
```

This happens:
[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8b22.png)

Comment: `insertMany` method takes an array of documents as input parameter. Is the input parameter an array of documents?

Comment: There is a typo.  There is an extra `{` at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments mentioned there is an extra { in the beginning, this should be the JSON:

[
{
"id": "001",
"type": "laptop",
"brand": "Apple",
"name": "Macbook air",
"price": 2000,
"size": {
"long": 12,
"width": 20,
"high": 5
},
"colour": "white",
"capacity": {
"weight": "1.4kg",
"memory": "8GB",
"HDD": "1TB"
}
},
{
"id": "002",
"type": "laptop",
"brand": "HP",
"name": "Model S",
"price": 1500,
"size": {
"long": 13,
"width": 25,
"high": 10
},
"colour": "blue",
"capacity": {
"weight": "1.4kg",
"memory": "10GB",
"HDD": "2TB"
}
},
{
"id": "003",
"type": "laptop",
"brand": "Dell",
"name": "Model X",
"price": 2500,
"size": {
"long": 15,
"width": 20,
"high": 15
},
"colour": "pink",
"capacity": {
"weight": "1.8kg",
"memory": "5GB",
"HDD": "1TB"
}
}
]